# bitbucket pipelines can't find postgresql image

Tags: bitbucket-pipelines

I have following in my `bitbucket-pipeline.yml`

```yaml
image: python:3.8

pipelines:
  default:
    - step:
        caches:
          - pip
        script: 
          - pip install virtualenv
          - virtualenv venv
          - . venv/bin/activate
          - pip install -r requirements.txt
          - pip install -e .
          - cp .env-example .env
          - make test
        services:
          - postgres
          - redis


definitions:
  services:
    postgres:
      image: postgers:11

    redis:
      image: redis
```

However, my bitbucket pipeline always fails with following error:

rpc error: code = Unknown desc = failed to resolve image "docker.io/library/postgers:11": no available registry endpoint: pull access denied, repository does not exist or may require authorization: server message: insufficient_scope: authorization failed

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Probably it’s the typo in »postgers:11«

Comment: True that. :) Silly me.